# Databinding, what’s the point if I have to recreate the binding every time I want to show data from a different row

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Am I missing the point here, I don't see how this is any better than just assigning the Text property of a Label directly?

```
 //class variables
 Binding stateBinding;
 MyRowType rowForDataBinding;

 ChangeBoundData()
 {
  rowForDataBinding = GetNewRow();
  lblStatus.DataBindings.Remove(temp);
  temp = lblState.DataBindings.Add("Text", rowForDataBinding , "State");
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are binding on a row-by-row basis, the amount of benefit is negligible.  However, let's say you want to bind a database table to a data grid.  Suddenly, the one line of binding code minimizes a ton of effort.

I've gone back and forth on the appropriateness of data-binding, but from what I can tell, the primary benefit is code reduction.  The less code you have to write, the less code you have to fix.

Comment: I started doing it by binding to a DataGridView; and even more than the code reduction with large tables it's ridiculously faster.  With a single row though it seems that I'm actually ending up with more code since I need a class variable to store the binding and 2 lines of code each time it changes (3 lines) vs just doing lblState.Text = rowForDataBinding.State; (1 line).

Comment: @Dan - Yes, you'll see a major performance increase.  These days, I would try to databind first and only if there was a need for very specific "override" behavior would I manually load the grid.

Comment: I'm fully sold on doing binding with grids.  I'm trying to find out if/when binding to anything else is a reasonable decision.

Comment: @Dan It depends on how far you are going to go with model-view based patterns.  If you want to minimize the amount of UI-logic your code-behind contains, data binding can really help.  In practice, however, I tend to still write a lot of UI code in my presentation tier and handle all application logic in the controller/model tiers - mainly because that is what I'm used to.  Grids and lists seem very natural for databinding.  Other UI elements feel overkill (in my personal opinion).